# How to find all opencl devices on a system?

Tags: c++, opencl

I have this code:

```
// http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html
cl_uint platformIdCount = 0;
clGetPlatformIDs(0, nullptr, &platformIdCount);

if (platformIdCount == 0) {
    std::cerr << "No OpenCL platform found" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Found " << platformIdCount << " platform(s)" << std::endl;
}

std::vector<cl_platform_id> platformIds(platformIdCount);
clGetPlatformIDs(platformIdCount, platformIds.data(), nullptr);

for (cl_uint i = 0; i < platformIdCount; ++i) {
    std::cout << "\t (" << (i + 1) << ") : " << GetPlatformName(platformIds[i]) << std::endl;
}

// http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDs.html
cl_uint deviceIdCount = 0;
clGetDeviceIDs(platformIds[1], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, nullptr,
    &deviceIdCount);

if (deviceIdCount == 0) {
    std::cerr << "No OpenCL devices found" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Found " << deviceIdCount << " device(s)" << std::endl;
}

std::vector<cl_device_id> deviceIds(deviceIdCount);
clGetDeviceIDs(platformIds[1], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, deviceIdCount,
    deviceIds.data(), nullptr);

for (cl_uint i = 0; i < deviceIdCount; ++i) {
    std::cout << "\t (" << (i + 1) << ") : " << GetDeviceName(deviceIds[i]) << std::endl;
}
```

and I am running it on a laptop that has 2 gpu, one HD4400 and GForce 750.

When I run it, I am getting two platform and each platform has the device for that specific manufacturer, for example on platform 0, I am getting i7 and HD4400 and on platform 1, I am getting GeForce 750.

I thought that I can get all devices from one platform?

Am I correct to believe to find a suitable device, I need to go over all platforms and find devices which are for GPU and then I have the list of all devices?

What is the correct way to find suitable device for a task?

Say I want to find GPU with maximum memory or maximum worker?

Is there any library that can help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

The OpenCL platform basically denotes the manufacturer. If you would have two (can be different models) Nvidia GPUs, they would be on the same platform. But Intel and Nvidia are different platforms.

Yes, you need to specifically select one device for your OpenCL computations. Therefore you iterate over all platforms and for every platform over all of its devices in order to get a list of all available OpenCL devices. Then from this list you can select the best/fastest one (in your case the GForce 750 as it is both faster than the HD4400 and has more video memory).

Here is some code that will give you a list of all available devices in the `devices` vector. Select the GeForce 750 with `devices[1]`.

```c
std::vector<Device> devices;
int find_devices() {
    std::vector<Platform> platforms; // get all platforms
    std::vector<Device> devices_available;
    int n = 0; // number of available devices
    Platform::get(&platforms);
    for(int i=0; i<(int)platforms.size(); i++) {
        devices_available.clear();
        platforms[i].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices_available);
        if(devices_available.size()==0) continue; // no device found in plattform i
        for(int j=0; j<(int)devices_available.size(); j++) {
            n++;
            devices.push_back(devices_available[j]);
        }
    }
    if(platforms.size()==0||devices.size()==0) {
        std::cout << "Error: There are no OpenCL devices available!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) std::cout << "ID: " << i << ", Device: " << devices[i].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;
    return n; // return number of available devices
}
```

---

For an easy start with OpenCL, I created a lightweight wrapper that vastly simplifies the OpenCL C++ bindings and eliminates the entire code overhead that comes with it. You can get the list of all available devices with `get_devices()` and automatically find the fastest device with `select_device_with_most_flops()`: https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper

Comment: I am trying to fix some old code that reports that my laptop has only 1 platform instead of two (intel & Nvidia), but your code returns also the same result. 

`OpenCL reports 1 platforms.

Platform 0: Intel(R) Corporation Intel(R) OpenCL OpenCL 2.0`

Instead, `CLinfo` detects both platforms, so what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: @Maverick although I never had problems with it, maybe the dedicated GPU is deactivated sometimes with Nvidia Optimus? You could try if setting it as the main GPU in the BIOS makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so many months from your initial answer. I have already thought that and I already tried to change the default graphics card under NVidia's Control Panel since there wasn't such an option in the BIOS. Didn't worked. After searching in different forums last night, I found the root of the problem. It was the drivers themselves. I installed the 64bit version of NVidia drivers, but I was trying to compile the program under the 32bit version. Switching to 64bit release it worked flawlessly, so the problem solved. I am wondering if I could also use a 32-bit version somehow!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get all devices in one platform.

At most, you'll just see devices from the same vendor grouped together (e.g., AMD CPU and AMD GPU, or Intel CPU and GPU). On Windows (and I presume Linux) you might see multiple platforms. On Mac OS X, I've only ever seen one (with the CPU and all GPUs).

You are correct that you need to iterate all platforms and all devices to find them all. You can filter to what you'll support, and sort based on capabilities.

Comment: Is there any library to help on this? For example, I pass requirement based on some flags (say DEVICE_GPU or DEVICE_MORE_MEMORY, ,,,) and it return all suitable devices sorted?

Comment: Depends on thick of a wrapper you want. The Khronos C++ wrapper helps some. Boost.Compute is another option.

Answer (score 1):

clinfo[1] utility and clinfo[2] utility show available platforms and devices information. They are good for local use. khronos clGetPlatformIDs and clGetDeviceIDs are good for runtime detection when distributing software.

1: https://github.com/Oblomov/clinfo 1: https://sf.net/p/clinfo