# OpenCL Platform Term

Tags: opencl, platform, xpu

I am trying to learn OpenCL on Intel FPGAs. I have a question on my mind. I know that the platform term for OpenCL refers to -not exactly but- vendors. If I have AMD CPU and AMD GPU, I have an AMD platform. However, I want to learn, if I have AMD CPU, Intel FPGA and NVIDIA GPU, does that mean I have 3 platforms? Instead of AMD CPU, if it was Intel CPU, does that mean platform number reduced to 2? Can someone clarify for what the platform term is used? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, OpenCL platforms refer to vendors, or rather, vendor OpenCL runtime drivers. With 1 Intel CPU, 2 Nvidia GPUs and 1 AMD GPU, you will have 3 Platforms, one for Intel, one for Nvidia and one for AMD. With an AMD CPU and AMD GPU, you will have a single Platform for both. Same with Intel CPU and Intel GPU/FPGA, also 1 Platform only.

Here an example for an exception to the Platforms=vendors rule: There is 1 Intel CPU in the system, but the Intel OpenCL runtime and also POCL OpenCL runtime installed. Then you have 2 Platforms (Intel and POCL), each with the same Intel CPU as device.

As for detecting all available devices on the system regardless of their Platform, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57336786/9178992).