# Using clang to compile .cl kernel file

Tags: c++, clang, opencl

My environment:

```
Ubuntu clang version 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.3
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

My problem:
when I do this:

```
$ clang -cl-std=CLC++ ./test.cl
```

in which ./test.cl file is:

```
template<class T>
T add( T x, T y )
{
    return x + y;
}
kernel void k(){}
```

an error raises that:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: in function _start': (.text+0x24): undefined reference to main'
```

I wonder how I can solve this problem? I can't even compile the simplest .cl file which supports C++ features. Thanks guys!

Comment: Use the `-c` option if you only want to compile code

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I succeed after adding `-c` command, now I get `.o` file, can I use this file to create a Opencl program by `clCreateProgramWithBinary()`?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/blog/offline-compilation-of-opencl-kernels-into-spir-v-using-open-source-tooling

Answer (score 1):

You don't compile .cl files with clang. You compile the .c/.cpp C/C++ source files. In the C/C++ code, you load the .cl file in as a string (`kernel_code`) and pass it to the [OpenCL C/C++ bindings](https://www.khronos.org/files/OpenCLPP12-reference-card.pdf) along with a [device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57336786/9178992). The executable will then at runtime compile the OpenCL C code from the `kernel_code` string and pass the vendor-specific assembly onto the device (GPU).

Here is the C++ code that does the CpenCL C compulation at runtime:

```c
//const cl::Device device = ...;
//const string kernel_code = ...;

cl::Context context = cl::Context(device);
cl::CommandQueue queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, device); // queue to push commands for the device
cl::Program::Sources source;
source.push_back({ kernel_code.c_str(), kernel_code.length() });
cl::Program program = cl::Program(context, source);
int error = program.build("-cl-fast-relaxed-math"); // compile OpenCL C code
if(error) cout << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(device) << endl; // print build log if errors occur during OpenCL C compiling
```

You then create `cl::Buffer` objects (allocate device memory), create `cl::Kernel` objects corresponding to the kernels in the OpenCL C code, link the buffers to the kernels in the correct order with `kernel.setArg(...);` and run the kernels in the `queue` with `queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(...);` and `queue.finish();`.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! The way you are describing is  online compilation, but I want offline compilation(into binary, so I can use clCreateProgramWithBinary()), so I followed [Clang user manual](https://releases.llvm.org/10.0.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#c-for-opencl) to do this, but I failed.

Comment: Hm... No, you totally do compile .cl with Clang. Most of the OpenCL implementations out there do just that, they have Clang under the hood. The question here is how to produce an object file that your particular OpenCL driver understand. If it supports SPIR or SPIR-V - good, you don't need anything else. Otherwise, things are going to be fun.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your target platform. You can use clang for an offline compilation of OpenCL binary kernels for AMD GCN architecture, for example (if you're using ROCm drivers). You can do it with some of the older OpenCL implementations that explicitly or implicitly support SPIR (prior to SPIR-V), since it was based on LLVM IR. For OpenCL platforms supporting SPIR-V you can add an extra step using a SPIR-V translator (e.g., https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-LLVM-Translator ).

Comment: Thank you very much, It seems like clang is just one step of the whole compiling process, I also posted this question on [OpenCL github](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Guide/issues/14), I've been told to check this [page](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Guide/blob/main/chapters/os_tooling.md), I am trying to go through this. Hopefully this will work :)

Comment: @Glinttsd yes, that's the right process, in case if your target implementation supports SPIR-V, and most of the up to date ones should. Fun starts when SPIR-V is not supported...

Comment: My current implementation is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti，I think it supports : ) I would not have the chance to enjoy the "fun" haha

Comment: @Glinttsd you're lucky then, you can use both SPIR-V and PTX backends.