# GPU not found by OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl, gpgpu, amd-processor

I am new to OpenCL and trying to get the information about installed platforms and devices in my Machine. There is only a single platform installed in my PC and OpenCL is easily detecting it. The following C code:

```
cl_uint num_platforms = 0;
cl_int err = 0;

err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, NULL, &num_platforms);
if(err != CL_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Failed to detect platforms");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Number of platforms detected: %u", num_platforms);
```

is giving the output:

```
Number of platforms detected: 1
```

Now when I try to get the devices present in this platform, OpenCL is not detecting it:

```
cl_platform_id platform;
cl_uint num_devices = 0;
cl_int err = 0;

err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL); // Because only one platform is present
if(err != CL_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Failed to detect platforms");
    exit(1);
}

err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, NULL, &num_devices);
if(err != CL_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Failed to detect any devices");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Number of devices detected: %u", num_devices);
```

When I run this code, I get the message:

```
Failed to detect any devices
```

However, the specifications of my PC says otherwise:

[image]

Also, when I looked up the GPU Specs in the AMD Radeon Software, I got the following:

[image]
[image]

Clearly, my device supports OpenCL Version 2.0. On the top of that, I also have PyOpenCL installed in my PC, which is easily detecting the iGPU:

[image]

Clearly, the problem is in the C code but I don't know where!

Following are my device's specs:

- **OS**: Windows 10
- **CPU**: Ryzen 3500u
- **GPU**: Radeon Vega 8 iGPU (gfx902)

I have installed the OpenCL SDK from [here](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/OCL-SDK/releases).

Comment: You only check for success of `clGetDeviceIDs()` - it would be useful to know if `clGetPlatformIDs()` failed before it to narrow down the the error is ocurring.  If `clGetPlatformIDs()` fails, `clGetDeviceIDs()` will also fail, but not necessarily because that call is wrong, but the preceding one.

Comment: @Clifford I have checked the success of `clGetPlatformIDs()` before and It successfully detected the only OpenCL platform installed on my machine. Since, I didn't wanted to throw the whole bulky code, I provided only the minimum reproducible code.

Comment: That information, and the code demonstrating it should be in the question.  Any reasonable person debugging this would check that, so by not including it, you have simply forced this necessary discussion and wasted time and words.

Comment: @Clifford I have edited my post and included the information and the code demonstrating it.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57336786/9178992

Comment: @ProjectPhysX I have only one OpenCL platform present in my PC (demonstrated in the question) so If I want to look for a device, I will expect it to be present in that platform only.

Comment: That's much clearer; however looking at the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDs.html) I see that the return value carries information on the nature of the lack of success.  That too will be useful diagnostic information.

Comment: The documentation is unclear, but I see no purpose in having `num_entries == 1` but `devices == NULL`.  It is saying "_get me a list of 1_", without providing anywhere to put the list.  The documentation says: "_If `devices` is not NULL, the `num_entries` must be greater than zero._"; it is perhaps implicit then (although ambiguous) that if `devices == NULL` then `num_entries` must be zero.  Given that he stated purpose of the function is  to: "_Obtain the list of devices available on a platform._" rather than simply a _count_ of devices, the semantics of `devices==NULL` seem ambiguous.

Comment: @Clifford You, sir, nailed it! I tried `clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_GET_DEVICE_ALL, 0, NULL, &num_entries)` and it successfully detected the device. Thank you so very much for putting time and energy to this problem.

Comment: Just reading the documentation and observing the ambiguities and applying Occam's razor - never used OpenCL ;-).  For what it is worth I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the signature:

```
cl_int clGetDeviceIDs( cl_platform_id platform,
                       cl_device_type device_type,
                       cl_uint num_entries,
                       cl_device_id *devices,
                       cl_uint *num_devices)
```

With:

```
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, NULL, &num_devices);
```

You are asking for a list of length 1 to be written to `NULL`.  The documentation does not appear explicitly preclude this combination, but the neither does it make much sense semantically.

If you simly want to retreive a count of the available devices in `num_entries`, then:

```
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &num_devices);
```

That will get you a count without retrieving an actual list.